# Displaying row values as column values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, wamp

I am having this table in SQL(XAMP)

```
item_name         category_name        category_id
----------------------------------------------------
Flash_disk        Accessories          1    
Fanta             Food                 2    
Printer           Accessories          1    
Sprite             Food                2
```

I am trying to display category_name column values as column values using this query and it displays very well as shown.
sql:

```
SELECT category_id, MAX(IF(`category_name` = "Food", item_name, NULL)) Food, MAX(IF(`category_name` = "Accessories", item_name, NULL)) Accessories
FROM categories
GROUP BY category_id
```

and the results are

```
category_id         Food           Accessories
---------------------------------------------------
1                   NULL            Printer
2                   Sprite           NULL
---------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way I can get all columns populated with values  than displaying null values
the results  to be like this:

```
category_id         Food           Accessories
---------------------------------------------------
1                   Fanta          Printer
2                   Sprite         Flash_disk   
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: And why would you want "Fanta" to be on the row with `category_id = 1`, when it is in category 2?

Comment: I can do away with category_id, my aim is to display the results in a table but avoid null values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That expected result doesn't make much sense.

For example, why would Fanta have category_id 1 according those results?

But this query almost gets similar results:

```
SELECT rownum, 
MAX(CASE WHEN category_name = 'Food' THEN item_name END) AS Food, 
MAX(CASE WHEN category_name = 'Accessories' THEN item_name END) AS Accessories
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    MAX(cat1.category_name) AS category_name,
    COUNT(*) AS rownum,
    cat1.item_name
    FROM categories cat1
    JOIN categories cat2 ON cat2.category_id = cat1.category_id 
     AND cat2.item_name <= cat1.item_name
    GROUP BY cat1.category_id, cat1.item_name
) q
GROUP BY rownum
ORDER BY rownum;
```

**Returns**

```
rownum  Food    Accessories
1       Fanta   Flash_disk
2       Sprite  Printer
```

Comment: Thanks This gives exactly what I wanted

Comment: Cool.  Btw, this solution was written to work also on MySql 7.x.  For MySql 8.0 I would have used the window function ROW_NUMBER.  Also, often when a field is named after the table name, then it's often the primary key of that table.  F.e.  systemuser.systemuser_id .  Maybe that data should be normalised.  Having 3 tables.  `category(category_id, category_name, ...), item(item_id, item_name, ...) categoryitems(id, category_id, item_id)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT category_id,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN `category_name` = 'Food' THEN  item_name END), 'Fanta') as Food, 
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN `category_name` = 'Accessories' THEN  item_name END), 'Flash_disk') as Accessories
FROM categories
GROUP BY category_id;
```

Comment: it is displaying but the problem if get fanta which is in food category in accessories column

Comment: @user3736334 . . . If fixed the answer.  Just use a different default answer for accessories.